# Remove multiple array elements by object property

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays, one is the items list and second one is a selected items list:

```js
const orig = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "First",
    price: "100",
    qty: "1",
    sum: 1
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Second",
    price: "100",
    qty: "1",
    sum: 1
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Third",
    price: "99",
    qty: "1",
    sum: 1
  }
];

const selected = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "First",
    price: "100",
    qty: "1",
    sum: 1
  }
  // {
  //   id: "2",
  //   name: "Second",
  //   price: "100",
  //   qty: "1",
  //   sum: 1
  // }
];
```

I can loop over 2 arrays at the same time:

```js
const arr = [];

orig.forEach((o) => {
  selected.forEach((s) => {
    if (o.id !== s.id) {
      arr.push(o);
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

It works fine, when `selected` array has only 1 item, but if `selected` array got at least 2 items (second item is commented) then it doesn't work. Main purpose of this code is to remove `selected` items from `orig` array.

Comment: Specifically `orig.filter(o => !selected.find(s => s.id === o.id))`

Comment: @evolutionxbox it did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in two lines of code

```js
const selectedIds = selected.map(({id}) => id)
```

This stores all the `id` values of objects from the `selected` array. Based on the example given, `selectedIds` will have the value `[ "1" ]`.

Then,

```js
const arr = orig.filter(object => !selectedIds.includes(object.id))
```

This remvoes any object from `orig` that has an `id` that is in the `selectedIds` array.

Full Solution:

```js
const selectedIds = selected.map(({id}) => id)
const arr = orig.filter(object => !selectedIds.includes(object.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line.

```js
const orig = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'First',
        price: '100',
        qty: '1',
        sum: 1,
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Second',
        price: '100',
        qty: '1',
        sum: 1,
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Third',
        price: '99',
        qty: '1',
        sum: 1,
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Fourth',
        price: '69',
        qty: '420',
        sum: '9001',
    },
];

const selected = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'First',
        price: '100',
        qty: '1',
        sum: 1,
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Second',
        price: '100',
        qty: '1',
        sum: 1,
    },
];

const removeSelected = (arr, selected) => {
    return arr.filter(({ id }) => !selected.some((obj) => obj.id === id));
};

console.log(removeSelected(orig, selected));
```